# math equation with underline has different heights

Tags: math-mode, align, soul, ulem

I struggle with some equations in my research paper. I want to underline some variable, because they are complex, but if I use \underline the line is not at the same level in my example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\begin{document}

%underline example
\begin{align}
m = -\dfrac{3}{2} z_\mathrm{p} \operatorname{Im}\{\underline{\psi}_1^{\angle k} \underline{i}_1^{\angle k *} \}
\end{align}

%ulem package example
\begin{align}
m = -\dfrac{3}{2} z_\mathrm{p} \operatorname{Im}\{\uline{\psi}_1^{\angle k}\uline{i}_1^{\angle k *} \}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

I hope you can read the example. I also wanted to use the ulem packages or soul package, but it didn't work with the \align environment.
I would be really happy if anybody could help me!

Thx
Max

Edit: I also added the example with ulem but still the same problem

Comment: Are you sure you want to underline? It's sometimes used in handwriting as a substitute for bold, but rarely in print.

Comment: We don't use to add “[solved]”; accepting an answer is the way to say it.

Comment: @egreg thanks for the advice about "[solved]"

Comment: @David Carlisle: I have to use this notation, its the common standard at my university

Comment: @Max strange but if you have to, I suppose you have to, but have ypu seen any published works using that notation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\vphantom{\psi}` helps. Then the underlining command for `i` sees the larger descender of `\psi`, while `\psi` is not visible:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\begin{document}

%underline example
\begin{align}
m = -\dfrac{3}{2} z_\mathrm{p} \operatorname{Im}\{\underline{\psi}_1^{\angle
k} \underline{i\vphantom{\psi}}_1^{\angle k *} \}
\end{align}

%ulem package example
\begin{align}
m = -\dfrac{3}{2} z_\mathrm{p} \operatorname{Im}\{\uline{\psi}_1^{\angle
k}\uline{i\vphantom{\psi}}_1^{\angle k *} \}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]